# Spark Hive: Filter rows of one DataFrame by the values of another DataFrame's column

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, spark-hive

I have the following two `DataFrames`:

```
DataFrame "dfPromotion":
date        | store
===================
2017-01-01  | 1    
2017-01-02  | 1


DataFrame "dfOther":
date        | store
===================
2017-01-01  | 1    
2017-01-03  | 1
```

Later I need to `union` both of the `DataFrames` above. But before I have to remove all rows of `dfOther` that have a `date` value, that is also contained in `dfPromotion`.

The result of the following `filtering` step should look like this:

```
DataFrame "dfPromotion" (this stays always the same, must not be changed in this step!)
date        | store
===================
2017-01-01  | 1    
2017-01-02  | 1


DataFrame "dfOther" (first row is removed as dfPromotion contains the date 2017-01-01 in the "date" column)
date        | store
===================
2017-01-03  | 1
```

Is there a way to do this in Java? I only found the `DataFrame.except` method herefore, but this checks all columns of the DataFrames. I need to **filter the second DataFrame just by the `date` column**, as other columns could be added later, which could contain different values...

Calling `dfOther.filter(dfOther.col("date").isin(dfPromotion.col("date")))` throws following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attribute(s) date#64 missing from date#0,store#13 in operator !Filter date#0 IN (date#64);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned about Spark Hive, can you try spark sql approach like below?

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc);
val dfpromotion = sqlContext.sql("select * from dfpromotion");

dfpromotion.show
+----------+-----+
|        dt|store|
+----------+-----+
|2017-01-01|    1|
|2017-01-02|    1|
+----------+-----+

val dfother = sqlContext.sql("select * from dfother");

dfother.show
+----------+-----+
|        dt|store|
+----------+-----+
|2017-01-01|    1|
|2017-01-03|    1|
+----------+-----+


val dfdiff = sqlContext.sql("select o.dt, o.store from dfpromotion p right         outer join dfother o on p.dt = o.dt where p.dt is null");
val dfunion = dfpromotion.union(dfdiff);


scala> dfunion.show
+----------+-----+
|        dt|store|
+----------+-----+
|2017-01-01|    1|
|2017-01-02|    1|
|2017-01-03|    1|
```

Comment: This did it for me, thank you very much. My final code now: `dfPromotion.join(dfOther, dfPromotion.col("date").equalTo(dfOther.col("date")), "right_outer").where(dfPromotion.col("date").isNull()).select(dfOther.col("date"), dfOther.col("store"));`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the subtract function,

```
dfOther.select("date").except(dfPromotion.select("date")).join(dfOther,'date').show()
```

Comment: Sorry, but there's no `DataFrame.subtract` method in the Spark API: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html

Comment: oh sorry. I had it used in pyspark and have used subtract in Java rdd. Had no idea it was removed for dataframe. Anyways, we have except function, you can use that in above line of code instead of subtract.It should work mostly.

Comment: The point with the `except` function is, that I have to filter the `dfOther` DataFrame just by the `date` column. So I can't use this method, else this would be the easiest way to go.

Comment: I believe we can, dfOther.select("date"), this returns a dataframe with just date column and similarly dfPromotion.select("date") as well. so, except between two dataframe with date column will return the result we needed. Just give it a try and let me know if I have missed something.

Comment: This returns only two tables, each containing just one column `date`. But I need all the column in the result, which are `date` and `store` in the case above.

Comment: This is how you did it, dfOther.select("date").except(dfPromotion.select("date")).join(dfOther,'date').show()

Comment: Yes, you're right, following code did the same for me: `  dfOther.select("date").except(dfPromotion.select("date")).join(dfOther, "date");
` Thanks for your help!